# Best solution for HDMI (or DVI) to RCA (or peritel)

Tags: hdmi, dvi, video-conversion, adapter, rca

I'm looking for some inexpensive but not fake / poor solution to display my future "Xtreamer Ultra" on an old tv (which only has RCA/peritel connectivity)...

Here is the product's profile http://xtreamer.net/ultra/

As you see, it only has HDMI and DVI video outputs ...
It would be great if there'd be some good solution which isn't going to cost me hundreds of euros...

Anyone's got an idea ?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. [shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are off topoc, so this is likely to be closed fairly soon.

Answer (score 1):

Get an HDMI-to-S-video (or similar) converter like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009EA7XIY).

[image: HDMI-to-S-video converter]

Comment: Still expensive ...
    What about this one ? `http://www.amazon.co.uk/PS3-HDMI-DVI-cable/dp/B000NWQULS/ref=sr_1_3?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1361270060&sr=1-3` ?    It's normally for PS3 but someone tested it and attested it's working on a raspberry pi

Comment: That is HDMI to DVI; both of those use the same signalling methods and it's just a cable with different connectors. s-video/composite both require changing the format with something like what is in the post here...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ! I found one for 31$ (`http://www.amazon.com/ViewHD-Universal-Composite-Converter-Standard/dp/B0080KN18K/ref=pd_sim_sbs_e_3`)but I wonder if it's ok (comments seems OK) and if there ain't still cheaper ...